# mysql query , not active companies

Tags: mysql

i don't know how to construct the mysql query correctly.

Im using temp tables in order to make the query work , but i would like to see if somebody can do that with one query, insted of using temp tables.

The two queries are simple.
1)

```
select distinct(AgencyChoiceTb.id) 
from AgencyChoiceTb , ClientDataTb , HistoryCreditTb
where ClientDataTb.Id = HistoryCreditTb.Client_Id 
    and ClientDataTb.Agency_choice_id = AgencyChoiceTb.id 
    and HistoryCreditTb.`Action` = 10 
    and HistoryCreditTb.Time between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-26'
```

and the second query is:

```
select distinct(AgencyChoiceTb.id) 
 from AgencyChoiceTb , ClientDataTb , HistoryCreditTb
where   HistoryCreditTb.Client_Id = ClientDataTb.Id 
 and ClientDataTb.Agency_choice_id = AgencyChoiceTb.id 
 and HistoryCreditTb.Time between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-30' 
  and HistoryCreditTb.`Action` = 10
group by AgencyChoiceTb.Agency_name
```

Now after creating temp table from first query and second query.
Im comparing the two created tables with AgencyChoiceTb.Agency_name NOT IN the second table.

How can i make one query without using temp tables?
I tryied with alias but when im doing NOT IN doesnt work, the result is wrong.

Thank you in advice

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should use explict join for a better readbility 
and the you could use a left join where thd id is null   not in subs

```
  select distinct(AgencyChoiceTb.id) 
  from AgencyChoiceTb 
  INNER JOIN  ClientDataTb  ON ClientDataTb.Agency_choice_id = AgencyChoiceTb.id 
  INNER JOIN HistoryCreditTb ON ClientDataTb.Id = HistoryCreditTb.Client_Id
      and HistoryCreditTb.`Action` = 10 
      and HistoryCreditTb.Time between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-26'
  LEFT JOIN (
    select distinct(AgencyChoiceTb.id) 
    from AgencyChoiceTb 
    INNER JOIN  ClientDataTb  ON ClientDataTb.Agency_choice_id = AgencyChoiceTb.id 
    INNER JOIN HistoryCreditTb ON ClientDataTb.Id = HistoryCreditTb.Client_Id
        and HistoryCreditTb.`Action` = 10 
        and HistoryCreditTb.Time between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-30'
  ) t on AgencyChoiceTb.id = td.id 
  where  t.id is null
```

or you could use a not in

```
  select distinct(AgencyChoiceTb.id) 
  from AgencyChoiceTb 
  INNER JOIN  ClientDataTb  ON ClientDataTb.Agency_choice_id = AgencyChoiceTb.id 
  INNER JOIN HistoryCreditTb ON ClientDataTb.Id = HistoryCreditTb.Client_Id
      and HistoryCreditTb.`Action` = 10 
      and HistoryCreditTb.Time between '2018-04-01' and '2018-04-26'
  where AgencyChoiceTb.id NOT IN  (
    select distinct(AgencyChoiceTb.id) 
    from AgencyChoiceTb 
    INNER JOIN  ClientDataTb  ON ClientDataTb.Agency_choice_id = AgencyChoiceTb.id 
    INNER JOIN HistoryCreditTb ON ClientDataTb.Id = HistoryCreditTb.Client_Id
        and HistoryCreditTb.`Action` = 10 
        and HistoryCreditTb.Time between '2018-03-01' and '2018-03-30'
  )
```